# Patching classes in Python

Tags: python, class, monkeypatching

Suppose I have a Python class that I want to add an extra property to.

Is there any difference between

```
import path.MyClass
MyClass.foo = bar
```

and using something like :

```
import path.MyClass
setattr(MyClass, 'foo', bar)
```

?

If not, why do people seem to do the second rather than the first? (Eg. here http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2008/10/chaining-monkey-patches-in-python.html )

Comment: Why not update you class's definition with the additional method?  Why do all this "magical" stuff when you can simply edit the class definition?

Comment: In my particular problem when I asked this, the class came from a library that we didn't want to change; and we couldn't subclass it. Though agree in general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statements are equivalent, but setattr might be used because it's the most dynamic choice of the two (with setattr you can use a variable for the attribute name.)

See: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: Agreed. In particular, this would be required the way patching was performed in the OP's referred-to blog entry - the name of the method was not known by the innards of the monkeypatch method.

Comment: thanks. But I updated the question because I still don't see that one is more dynamic than the other

Comment: ah ... no, I see what you mean   ... sorry .. doh!